# Angular child component initialization problem

Tags: angular, typescript, user-interface, viewchild

I am a beginner in Angular and I got the following problem when I try to initialize a child select component: I want to display a list based on the selected element (even on the page load) and the setter method of the select component is called infinitely over and over again. If I remove the subscribe from there everything is fine, but actually I need it so the list will be filled correctly on page load. Can you help me to figure out what I am doing wrong or how to do this in another way?

```
@ViewChild(ChildComponent) set childComponent(value: ChildComponent) {
if (value !== undefined) {
  this._childComponent= value;
  this.service.getList(this._childComponent.selectedElement).subscribe(result => {
    this.list= result;
  });
}}

refresh(): void {
this.service.getList(this._childComponent.selectedElement).subscribe(result => {
  this.list= result;
});}

<childComponent*ngIf="selectedElement!== null" (change)="refresh()"></childComponent>
```

Comment: You're better off passing the selected value to you child component, then initializing your list of values.